# Kernel died restarting jupyter notebook

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

While executing python code in Jupyter notebook,"kernel died and restarting jupyter notebook" error occurred.The code uses opencv library.

Comment: Is it because of using cv2 windows?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite relevant to your case but it might be relevant to someone else. I had the same problem...2 potential causes: using `quit()` command in Jupyter. The second cause in my case was using Pandas: `display(df)`...I think that the cause could be triggered by an output is that is too large to display (e.g. very large text output). I suggest the following approach: run the program on a line by line basis till you find the exact line causing the problem. This is how I found out that  `display(df)` is what was breaking Jupyter...when I took this line out the program ran without problems. If you have a large output display part of it, not all.